# LINQ to Entities: Create new table (entity) in the database

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am making a c# application that has a user profiles, every time a new profile is created a table with the profile name should be created in the database, I am using SQL server for my database.

I am using LINQ-to-Entities in my application to generate the entities of the pre-made tables in my SQL server database that has the main data of my application. The problem is that I don't know how, if possible, to create the table for every new user ?

Comment: Why are you creating a table for every user? And you can use `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("create table...")` to execute a non query command. Not sure if this is the best way; I've never create a table outside of migrations with EF.

Comment: I cannot think of any reason why you'd want to do that. You wouldn't be able to use LINQ to Entities to access these tables even you did create a table for each profile. Find a DBA quick and ask him to talk some sense into this design!

Comment: There should be a users table and then add a row for each user.

Comment: @gerdi: each user has his own achievements (200+), how can I add all this details in a single row. If there is a better and optimized way than this then I am all ears.

Comment: @Tima Achievements is then its own table with the foreign key to the users table , with a one to many relationship. each user cannot have their own table.

Comment: @gerdi ok, got it, that will be much better than creating tons of tables. Thanks.